# pulseaudio: the monitor of the null-sink doesn't work

Tags: pulse-audio

I created a null-sink (ubuntu 18.04, pactl 11.1) whose monitor I  loop back into my sound card but for unknown reason, when I play something onto the sink, the monitor of the null-sink  is static and it is not muted. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#start from a fresh configuration: the server is deleted and then recreated, 
  pulseaudio -k
  sleep 4

#create null-sink and loopback to sound card

  pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=appoutput sink_properties=device.description='appoutput'

  pactl load-module module-loopback  source='appoutput.monitor' sink='alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo' 

  pactl set-default-sink 'appoutput' 

exit 0
```

Actually, I tried just with the creation of the null sink without the loopback and in pavucontrol I can see that the slider of appoutput.monitor doesn't move (static). When I launch VLC for instance, it plays fine on the null sink but the monitor nothing.

I reinstalled pulseaudio, same thing.

Any help very welcome, can't figure out the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I managed to get it working by deleting the pulseaudio config file which was supposedly corrupt. (rm -rf $HOME/.config/pulse)

Then the above script executed correctly.

Comment: It helped in my case, too. But it remains unclear which setting did this.